# bootstrap popover with textarea: can't resize horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, textarea, popover

I can't drag-resize a textarea's width when it's within a bootstrap popover:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/273911/

Or in code:

```
<button id="popoverBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">
Click to toggle popover
</button>

$(function () {
  $('#popoverBtn').popover({
    'title': 'this is a textarea test with a long title',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click hover',
    content: document.createElement('textarea')
  });
})
```

Strangely, I haven't found any known issues describing such a behavior. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding

> Strangely, I haven't found any known issues describing such a
>   behavior. What could be the reason for this behavior?

the answer resides in [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/)

> textarea's are modified to only be resizable *vertically* as
>   horizontal resizing often “breaks” page layout.

This behavior could be *overridden* by specifying `resize:"both"` and explicit `maxWidth` to prevent `textarea` to overlap the parent container as demonstrated below:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#popoverBtn').popover({
    'title': 'this is a textarea test with a long title',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click hover',
    content: createContent()
  })
  .on("show.bs.popover", function() {
    const parentEl = $(this).data("bs.popover").getTipElement();
  });
})


function createContent(){
   var textArea = $('<textarea class="textarea-resiable" />'); 
   textArea.css({resize:"both",maxWidth: '250px'});
   return textArea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<button id="popoverBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Click to toggle popover</button>
```